# Incorrect option selected

Tags: firefox, forms, xhtml

I've created a combo box in a form using the following:

```
<select id="end_minute" name="end_minute">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

In Firefox, he first option is selected, but in IE the option with attribute `selected="selected"` is (correctly) shown.

**Update**

Pekka is right, the values were being cached by Firefox

Comment: I tried just now in both IE and FF3.6, they both select the last one

Comment: tried with Firefox 3.5.*, last option selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably re-loading the page after having selected the first option. Firefox will memorize form values in that case. When you go to the address field and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should return to normal.

Comment: Or just hold `Shift` then click refresh.

Comment: I use [Ctrl]+[F5] to force a full redraw.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox are you running? As it seems to do exactly as it is supposed to in my browsers...

FF 3.5.7
FF 3.6
Chrome

Try another browser. Or post your browser info so we can examine it better.